# Javers and MyBatis integration help needed

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis, javers

I'm having issues trying to get MyBatis and Javers (with Spring) integrated and working. I've followed instructions at http://javers.org/documentation/spring-integration/ and gotten the Aspect setup, and annotated my entity class and registered it with Javers, and the MyBatis interface correctly annotated with @Repository and @JaversAuditable on the appropriate methods, but still haven't gotten it to work, even setting breakpoints in the Javers Aspect, but nothing triggers.

I've also gone about it the other way, using MyBatis plugin interceptor, as per http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/configuration.html#plugins (then used http://www.mybatis.org/spring/xref-test/org/mybatis/spring/ExecutorInterceptor.html as a basic example for commits). However while it's triggering, it's not doing what I expected and is basically just an aspect around on the commit method, which takes a boolean rather than containing which entity(ies) are being commited which would let me pass them to Javers. I suppose I could add an interceptor on the update/insert MyBatis methods, and then stored that in a ThreadLocal or similar so that when commit/rollback was called I could pass it to Javers as necessary, but that's messy.

I've got no clue where to go from here, unless someone can see something I've missed with one of those 2 methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So in my confusion, I realized that since MyBatis generates the concrete object for the Mapper Interfaces, Spring never seems the creation of that object, simply has the final object registered as a Bean in the context. Thus, Javers never has a chance to process the Bean as it's created in order to do any proxying or what not as necessary.

So, silly me. So I ended up creating a Spring-Data @Repository layer that mostly just passes the call through to the Mapper. Although on updates I'm doing some extra bits which the DAO shim layer (as I'm calling it) works well for.